# Get list by id in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have lists i get it from api. This lists have sublist. Sublist have list id. I need to get sublists from api and show when parent list clicked. How i can do it?
This is my lists:

```
function getType1() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get("http://mobile.unimax.kz/api/type1api")
        .success(function (data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
            $scope.type1 = data;
        })
        .error(function () {
            deferred.reject();
        });
}
getType1();
```

this is mysublist:

```
$scope.getType2 = function (id) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get("http://mobile.unimax.kz/api/type2api/" + id)
        .success(function (data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
            console.log(data);
            $scope.type2 = data;
            $state.go('tab.catalog2', {
                id: id
            });
        })
        .error(function () {
            deferred.reject();
        });
}
```

this is how show my list:

```
 <ul class="list">
        <li class="item item-icon-right" ng-repeat="type in type1" ng-click="getType2({{type.id}})">
            <h4>{{type.type11}}</h4>
            <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to interpolate, just use `ng-click="getType2(type.id)"`

Comment: but it downloaded and returned data. but it is not showing

Comment: well, then you have to debug or provide plunker/fiddle.